# Returning an object with async/await in node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await

So I am playing around with node.js and trying to get push some data to an object from a function. Everything is being parsed correctly with the regex, I guess I just don't understand how to implement what I am doing correctly. I am getting undefined on the json objects after I parse the game data.

```
const diplo = `!report Game Type: Diplo
1: <@12321321421412421>
2: <@23423052352342334>
3: <@45346346345343453>
4: <@23423423423523523>`


var diplo_data = {players:[]};

async function gameType(game) {
    let data = {};
    let game_types = [{id: 1, name: 'Diplo'}, {id: 2, name: 'Always War'}, {id: 3, name: 'FFA'}
        , {id: 4, name: 'No Diplo'}, {id: 5, name: 'Team'}, {id: 6, name: 'Duel'}, {id: 7, name: 'No War'}];
    let o = {}
    let reType = /!report Game Type:\s+?(\d|\w+)\s?(\w+\s?(\w+)?)?\n/gi
    let match = reType.exec(game)
    if(match[1]){
        for (var j = 0; j < game_types.length; j++) {
            if ((game_types[j].name).toLowerCase() === (match[1]).toLowerCase()) {
                data.type = game_types[j].id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(match[2]){
        data.moddifier = match[2]
    }
    console.log(data)
    await (data)
}

async function main() {

    console.log("Reading diplo data...\n\r")
    try {
        diplo_data = await gameType(diplo)
        console.log(diplo_data)
    } catch (err) {
        return 'No game type!';
    }        
}

main();
```

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You must add `return` statement before `await (data)`. But the main question is why do you use `async/await` there? `gameType` is not asynchronous function.

Comment: I'm going to be inserting the data into a database and need to do multiple inserts into different tables so need to do it as a transaction.

Comment: So async functions are made for asynchronous code. It looks like all your stuff is synchronous. You don't need to use async functions here.

Comment: Why are you using async/await?

Comment: @alexmac , if you want to expand comment to an answer I'll give you a + just for being mr. obvious otherwise I'm going to delete the question in next couple days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix the bug in your code, you must add `return` statement before `await (data)`:

```
async function gameType(game) {
  ...
  return await (data);
}
```

But the main question is **why do you use `async/await` there**? `gameType` is not asynchronous function, it doesn't contain any async calls. It should be declared as a regular *synchronous* function:

```
function gameType(game) {
   ...
   return data;
}
```

The function `main` which calls `gameType`, should be declared without `async` too.

```
function main() {
  console.log("Reading diplo data...\n\r");
  try {
    diplo_data = gameType(diplo);
    console.log(diplo_data);
  } catch (err) {
     return 'No game type!';
  }        
}
```

Comment: can we use async and await function without returning a promise ?

Comment: If a function is declared with `async` keyword it returns promise in any case, even you explicitly don't return the result.